# How to remove a record from many-to-many relationship table in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have three table.

```
__lesson__ __lesson_student___ __student__
id   name   id les_id   std_id    id   name
1    Math   1  1(Math)  1(Bob)    1   Bob
2    Phys.  2  2(Phys)  1(Bob)    2   Alice
            3  1(Math)  2(Alice)
```

I want to remove Math from Bob.How can I do that? I want to only remove **lesson_student** 's id(1).
I have many to many relationship between lesson and student.
I CAN add a student to lesson.But I CAN'T remove lesson from student.nothing happens when I remove lesson from student's collection and update student.

**Lesson.class**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "studentLessons", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
public Set<User> getLessonStudents() {
    return lessonStudents;
}
```

and **User.class**

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "lesson_student", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uq_student_lesson", columnNames = {
        "student_id", "lesson_id" }), joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "lesson_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
public Set<Lesson> getStudentLessons() {
    return studentLessons;
}
```

I use below code for removing:

```
    @Override
public void removeLessonFromUser(Lesson les) {
    try {
        final String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getName();
        final Criteria criteria = openSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        User user = new User();
        user = (User) criteria.uniqueResult();

        log.info(user.getStudentLessons());
        user.getStudentLessons().remove(les);
        log.info(user.getStudentLessons());

        updateUser(user);

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I googled.I saw orphanRemoval and its work only on one-to-many.What do I need?Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what I mentioned in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the `lesson` object from set of `studentLessons` and hibernate will take care of deleting the record from the join table.

Here is the sample code:

```
    Session session = sessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Student s = (Student) session.get(Student.class, 1);
    System.out.println(s.getName());

    Set<Lesson> lessons = s.getStudentLessons();

    Lesson les = (Lesson) session.get(Lesson.class, 2);
    lessons.remove(les);

    //session.update(s); -- This is not required as hibernate will do dirty checking.
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

Comment: I updated my question please look again.I use spring with hibernate.So I use transaction in service layer.So I'm not need start transaction like your codes.I  am already doing it this way.But nothing happens.

Comment: You're assigned to a separate Set.this important part?

Comment: @erginduran, the main point to note here is to remove the `Lesson` object from the collection of lessons the student is mapped to within the Hibernate session.

Comment: @erginduran, By the way, no where in your question you have said you are using Spring, so I answered on how it can be achieved using plain Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) But I say again.It does not work for me.When I tried,nothing happens.I am seeing student.getStudentLessons().size() on console with logger so remove from collection but dont update.